# Firebase Storage: safe way to get relative path of a file? (Storing HTML file)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security, banner

Hello StackOverflow and Firebase Community!

I am trying to achieve something that is probably not intended with Firebase: I want to store HTML folders (banner ads in my case) in Firebase Storage.

My question is: **How to keep the relative path from my HTML file to the related JS and image files**.

So this files could easily find each-other:

> /path/to/my/folder/index.html
>
> /path/to/my/folder/main.js
>
> /path/to/my/folder/picture.jpg

```
<html>
...
<script src="main.js">
...
</html>
```

```
document.onload = function() {
    myImage.src = 'picture.jpg'
}
```

These relative URLs are not working if I store all the files on Firebase Storage, and access them with their DownloadURL, with looks like `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-project.appspot.com/o/my_folder_300x250%2Findex.html?alt=media&token=12a123a1-1234-1a1a-1234-a1ab123456a1`,

I can make the files reachable without token by opening Firebase's security rules, but the relative path is still broken because of the URL parameters, and the folder path being escaped.

I also managed to make it work on an other project by **making the Google Cloud Storage bucket public**. I can access the files and keep the relative path using an URL like: `https://my-project.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com/path/to/my/folder/my_folder_300x250/index.html`. This works great, but has **major security flaws** that I want to prevent, like listing all the files in the bucket

---

I tried to save my banners as zip files, unzip them on the front end side, and recreate the folder structure in browser with the FileSystem API. But I'm limited to Chrome.

---

I could also try to replace all the URLs in my HTML, JS and CSS files, but this doesn't feel like a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found a pretty simple solution:

In Google Cloud Console, I created a new role that has get access, but no list access, and applied it to `allUsers`, with the following permissions.

> resourcemanager.projects.get
>
> storage.objects.get

This will solve my issues for now, and I'll keep accessing data using links like `https://my-project.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com/path/to/my/folder/my_folder_300x250/index.html` instead of firebase's downloadURL().

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Storage is built around Cloud Storage, which doesn't actually have directories, but a flat namespace. Directories are emulated via the storage object naming convention: names can contain the `/` character and placing a "directory" path at the beginning of the object name makes that object appear to be in that "directory". See 
[How Subdirectories Work](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork).

So your only solution (if you want to store the files independently) is to process all references, make the "paths" absolute and name the files accordingly. As you observed, you probably need to take into account all the URL query parameters as well.